# Binary Marshaller in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, caching, ignite

We create/update table schema at run time as per the user.
How can we update QueryEntity for a Cache at run time and add columns for queries with SqlFieldsQuery.

So basically any example of 
"It enables you to add and remove fields from objects of the same type. Given that server nodes do not have model classes definitions, this ability allows dynamic change to an objects structure, and even allows multiple clients with different versions of class definitions to co-exist." as per Apache Ignite?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the current version of Ignite. It will be added in the next few months in the scope of this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-735

Comment: I assume this means that with ignite version 1.6 we cannot add new queryEntities (i.e. fields which can be used in sql queries) and queryIndexes (i.e. fields on which indexes are created) both at runtime. Is that right?

Comment: @AndyDufresne Yes, this is correct. SQL schema is static for now and is created on the cache start. I.e., the only way to change it is to destroy the cache completely and recreate with new configuration.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. This is an important feature. Will wait for 1.7 to have the fix.